# How to categorize text the most efficient way?

Tags: openai-api, large-language-model

I have a table with `<message_body>` and `<city>`
Body contains posts on the forum.

I want to use openAI to classify it to one of my 5 tags.

I have some train data where I classified 20 messages, I can provide more examples of the model if needed.

Comment: While my answer is not fixed yet, I pivoted my search a bit. For now, I will be trying to adopt this tool for my task
https://paperswithcode.com/paper/distilbert-a-distilled-version-of-bert#code

basically, I plan to utilize my own LLM to save up on the costs of openAI

Still I am interested i nthe answer for the original  question